# A Normal Distribution Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, statistics, normal-distribution

so im trying to make a program to solve various normal distribution questions with pure python (no modules other than `math`) to 4 decimal places only for A Levels, and there is this problem that occurs in the function `get_z_less_than_a_equal(0.75):`. Apparently, without the assert statement in the except clause, the variables all get messed up, and change. The error, i'm catching is the recursion error. Anyways, if there is an easier and more efficient way to do things, it'd be appreciated.

```
import math

mean = 0
standard_dev = 1
percentage_points = {0.5000: 0.0000, 0.4000: 0.2533, 0.3000: 0.5244, 0.2000: 0.8416, 0.1000: 1.2816, 0.0500: 1.6440, 0.0250: 1.9600, 0.0100: 2.3263, 0.0050: 2.5758, 0.0010: 3.0902, 0.0005: 3.2905}

def get_z_less_than(x):
    """
    P(Z < x)
    """
    return round(0.5 * (1 + math.erf((x - mean)/math.sqrt(2 * standard_dev**2))), 4)

def get_z_greater_than(x):
    """
    P(Z > x)
    """
    return round(1 - get_z_less_than(x), 4)

def get_z_in_range(lower_bound, upper_bound):
    """
    P(lower_bound < Z < upper_bound)
    """
    return round(get_z_less_than(upper_bound) - get_z_less_than(lower_bound), 4)

def get_z_less_than_a_equal(x):
    """
    P(Z < a) = x
    acquires a, given x


    """
    # first trial: brute forcing
    for i in range(401):
        a = i/100
        p = get_z_less_than(a)
        if x == p:
            return a
        elif p > x:
            break
    # second trial: using symmetry
    try: 
        res = -get_z_less_than_a_equal(1 - x)
    except:
    # third trial: using estimation
        assert a, "error"
        prev = get_z_less_than(a-0.01)
        p = get_z_less_than(a)
        if abs(x - prev) > abs(x - p):
            res = a
        else:
            res = a - 0.01
    return res

def get_z_greater_than_a_equal(x):
    """
    P(Z > a) = x
    """
    if x in percentage_points:
        return percentage_points[x]
    else:
        return get_z_less_than_a_equal(1-x)

    
print(get_z_in_range(-1.20, 1.40))
print(get_z_less_than_a_equal(0.7517))
print(get_z_greater_than_a_equal(0.1000))
print(get_z_greater_than_a_equal(0.0322))
print(get_z_less_than_a_equal(0.1075))
print(get_z_less_than_a_equal(0.75))
```

Comment: You can help others help you by saying in more detail in what way the variables got messed up. It would probably help to give a case in which things go wrong and explain what you expected and what you actually got.

Comment: are you trying to get the pdf value given mean, std_dev for any input value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since python3.8, the `statistics` module in the standard library has a `NormalDist` class, so we could use that to implement our functions "with pure python" or at least for testing:

```py
import math
from statistics import NormalDist

normal_dist = NormalDist(mu=0, sigma=1)

for i in range(-2000, 2000):
    test_val = i / 1000
    assert get_z_less_than(test_val) == round(normal_dist.cdf(test_val), 4)
```

Doesn't throw an error, so that part probably works fine

Your `get_z_less_than_a_equal` seems to be the equivalent of [NormalDist.inv_cdf](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.NormalDist.inv_cdf)

There are very efficient ways to compute it accurately using the inverse of the error function (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Inverse_functions) and [Python implementation](https://github.com/dougthor42/PyErf/blob/master/pyerf/pyerf.py#L290)), but we don't have that in the standard library

Since you only care about the first few digits and `get_z_less_than` is [monotonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function), we can use a simple [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) to find our solution

[Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) would be much faster, and not too hard to implement since we know that the derivative of the cdf is just the pdf, but still probably more complex than what we need

```py
def get_z_less_than_a_equal(x):
    """
    P(Z < a) = x
    acquires a, given x
    """
    if x <= 0.0 or x >= 1.0:
        raise ValueError("x must be >0.0 and <1.0")
    min_res, max_res = -10, 10
    while max_res - min_res > 1e-7:
        mid = (max_res + min_res) / 2
        if get_z_less_than(mid) < x:
            min_res = mid
        else:
            max_res = mid
    return round((max_res + min_res) / 2, 4)
```

Let's test this:

```py
for i in range(1, 2000):
    test_val = i / 2000
    left_val = get_z_less_than_a_equal(test_val)
    right_val = round(normal_dist.inv_cdf(test_val), 4)
    assert left_val == right_val, f"{left_val} != {right_val}"
 
# AssertionError: -3.3201 != -3.2905
```

We see that we are losing some precision, that's because the error introduced by `get_z_less_than` (which rounds to 4 digits) gets propagated and amplified when we use it to estimate its inverse (see [Wikipedia - error propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty) for details)

So let's add a "digits" parameter to `get_z_less_than` and change our functions slightly:

```py
def get_z_less_than(x, digits=4):
    """
    P(Z < x)
    """
    res = 0.5 * (1 + math.erf((x - mean) / math.sqrt(2 * standard_dev ** 2)))
    return round(res, digits)


def get_z_less_than_a_equal(x, digits=4):
    """
    P(Z < a) = x
    acquires a, given x
    """
    if x <= 0.0 or x >= 1.0:
        raise ValueError("x must be >0.0 and <1.0")
    min_res, max_res = -10, 10
    while max_res - min_res > 10 ** -(digits * 2):
        mid = (max_res + min_res) / 2
        if get_z_less_than(mid, digits * 2) < x:
            min_res = mid
        else:
            max_res = mid
    return round((max_res + min_res) / 2, digits)
```

And now we can try the same test again and see it passes

Comment: thank you very much, i want to know how your `get_z_less_than_a_equal` function works, it seems so elegant.

Comment: The bisection method works by starting with an interval (in this case [-10;10]) and at each iteration halving the interval until it becomes small enough. To halve the interval we test function at the middle point: if the result is too high we set the middle as the new upper bound, if the result is too low we set the middle as the new lower bound. [Here is a gif from Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Bisection_anime.gif) `a` and `b` are the lower and upper bounds, `c` is the midpoint

Comment: wish i knew about this, is there anyway i can stumble across more things like this, in the future?